# WebKit request not creating a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
function onInitFs(fs) {

  fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {create: true, exclusive: true}, function(fileEntry) {

    // fileEntry.isFile === true
    // fileEntry.name == 'log.txt'
    // fileEntry.fullPath == '/log.txt'

  });
}
```

`window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, onInitFs);`

This is simply a script I have obtained from a tutorial. This is meant to create a file, supposedly in the "root directory of the app". I have pasted this in Chrome. I tried finding it in my C Drive but cant. Help please?

Comment: Thanks for editing it my bad

Comment: "I have pasted this in Chrome." — Where in Chrome?

Comment: @Quentin Well I actually meant pasting it in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/LocalFileSystem):

> The LocalFileSystem interface of the File System API gives you access to a **sandboxed** file system.

It doesn't store the data as a regular file on your regular file system. It stores it in the root directory of the app's *virtual* file system where it is, effectively, accessible only to the File System API.

Comment: So where could I find it if not

Comment: Can I have some help with that? I've tried it and read this tutorial http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/ but it doesn't create a file, and it's not clear where the file is made.

Comment: See the section titled "Reading a file by name" in that tutorial

Comment: How are you determining that it doesn't create a file? Does it throw some kind of error when you try to read it with the code in that example?

Comment: Wait i'm not asking to read a file, I want to know how to actually create a file.

Comment: @ZimbabweElephant — You appear to have code that creates a file already. Attempting to read the data back from it will test to see if that worked or not.

Comment: Oh I see, so the file is not actually created in the local file system?

Comment: @ZimbabweElephant — Correct. The file is created in the virtual file system.

Comment: So if i used the script in this question, and then put the read function after it, i can test if it's acutally been created without errors\?

Comment: Since it is appears to be asynchronous you would have to trigger the read in the callback after the write.

Comment: got it to alert(this.result). nothing appears but it doesn't say undefined which means it has worked.Now I can write to it

Comment: yes. I'm glad i got it to work. It now creates a file and writes something to it, and i've made it displays what is wrote on it. Thank you!

Comment: Now how would I make it create files in a for loop with different names?

Comment: With a for loop, presumably.

Comment: Nevermind, I've done that too. All names are the index of the for loop, so i think i've completed what i wanted to get done, thanks

Comment: Just one more question : How could I make an array in the file and push things into it? I want to push this into it : 'var blob = new Blob([r[i]["Name"]] + "\n", {type: 'text/plain'});' but push it into an array that's already there

Comment: Files contain strings, not JavaScript data structures. You'll need to serialize and deserialize to and from JSON or some other text based data format.

Comment: thanks. And I found a slight problem. It overrites the current data. Can i make it so it just adds it on?